# Short circuit variable sequence override

Tags: c#, short-circuiting

I am working in a C# based program. I am attempting to create a short circuit conditional statement:

```
if(safety() == 'Yes' && reason() == 'Yes')
{
    allowed = true;
}
```

The way the software is set up, however, the software perpetually views the "reason" variable as the first condition in the if statement, no matter what order I record the variables in. This is causing the 2nd variable to always run, when really, I only need it to run when "safety" == 'Yes'.

This is a long-winded way to ask: Is there any way to override the default sequence of the variables for this one instance in the script?

Comment: Do you mean that only one has to be true (`safety()`, `reason()`, or both)? If so, just use an or (`||`) instead of an and (`&&`)

Comment: First off that's not value C# because strings use double quotes.

Comment: @juharr I'm hoping that it's pseudo-code :)

Comment: They both need to be true. So if "safety" is false, "reason" should never be checked. Unfortunately, it seems as though the default is always checking "reason" first.

Comment: yes, it is just pseudo-code. sorry about that.

Comment: If `safety()` returns something other than `"Yes"` then `reason` will not be called.  Are you sure that `safety` isn't returning `"Yes"`?  It should also call `safety` before `reason`.  Alternatively if you use `&` instead of `&&` it will not short circuit and it would always call both.

Comment: C# will already short circuit if the first condition isn't true when using and. Are you sure it is being evaluated by .NET and not the application you're using?

Comment: If the application you're using is for some reason evaluating it itself then you might have to contact the developer or use a nested if statement. Certainly the behaviour you describe isn't how C# works.

Comment: @juharr safety() is definitely not returning yes and I am using &&, I think it's more closely related to the application being used

Comment: @John I believe it is being evaluated by the application, I think a nested if statement is probably what I need to figure out

Comment: C#'s `&&` and `||` operators are **always** short circuiting  (if you want to get around it, you can fake it with two Booleans and the `&` and `|` operators).  But, (assuming you mean `"Yes"` and not `'Yes'`), if `safety()` does not return the string `"Yes"` (upper-case "Y" and lower-case "es"), `reason()` will never be evaluated.

Comment: @Jay: You say "safety() is definitely not returning yes and...".  There's a difference between `yes` and `Yes`.  They are not equal strings if you are using `==` to check for equality.